# Two times send and recv are not working C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, send, recv

I was running into a problem i couldnt really solve so I restarted.
I had a problem with Data encapsulation or more specific with no encapsulation. So after I figured out, that encapsulation is useful, I started rewriting the code.

Now I run into a different Problem. Somehow my send and recv calls are not working as I want them to be.

Here is the part where I send:

```
char to_send[] = "hello. I am the Data.";

  // get size of data
  int len = strlen(to_send);
  char slen[len];
  sprintf(slen,"%d",len);
  printf("%s\n",slen);
  // send size of data
  if(send(comm_fd,slen,len,0)<0){perror("Error on send"); exit(1);}

  // send data
  if(send(comm_fd,to_send,len,0)<0){perror("Error on send"); exit(1);}
```

And here Part where I recv:

```
// getting size of bytes to recv
  char buf[1000];
  bzero(buf,1000);

  int rec = recv(comm_fd, buf, 100,0);
  printf("rec\n: %i",rec);
  printf("buf\n: %s\n", buf);

  int buffsize;
  buffsize = atoi(buf);
  bzero(buf,1000);
  printf("buffsize: %i\n",buffsize);

  // recv the bytes
  bzero(buf,1000);
  rec = recv(comm_fd, buf, buffsize,0);
  printf("rec\n: %i",rec);
  printf("%s",buf);
```

So my problem now is: I can recv the size of the next Data and print it. But the Data itself is not showing up.

Can someone help me? I think I'm doing major things wrong (I'm new to C and to Network programming)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `slen`'s size is not `len`

Answer (score 3):

Two things with that first `send` call:

```
if(send(comm_fd,slen,len,0)<0){perror("Error on send"); exit(1);}
```

Here you send `len` number of bytes, but `len` is the length of `to_send` and not the length of `slen`. You will most likely send data from outside the initialized parts of `slen` which leads to *undefined behavior*

The second problem is that you send the length of `to_send` as a variable-length string, so the received doesn't actually know how much to receive. In your case you could actually (and probably do) receive the length *and* the string in a single `recv` call. At least if you're using TCP (*streaming*) sockets.

Both of these problems can be solved by making `slen` a fixed-size array, big enough to hold the largest numbers you can think of (ten digits is usually enough), and then send this fixed-length array using `sizeof slen` .

Perhaps something like this:

```
// Ten digits, plus string terminator
char slen[10 + 1];

// Prefix length with zeroes, and don't overflow the buffer
snprintf(slen, sizeof(slen), "%010d", strlen(to_send));

// Send the whole array, including terminator
send(comm_fd, slen, sizeof slen, 0);
```

Then on the receiving side, you could do

```
// Ten digits, plus string terminator
char slen[10 + 1];

// Receive the whole string, including terminator
recv(comm_fd, slen, sizeof(slen), 0);

// Convert to a number
size_t len = strtoul(slen, NULL, 10);

// Now receive `len` bytes
```

<sub>Note that I have no error checking, which you should have.</sub>

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot! I see my mistakes ad will read about the functions you used. thanks

Comment: Also, in modern programs use `memset` instead of `bzero`  (wich is deprecated by POSIX)

Comment: `snprintf(slen, sizeof(slen), "%010d", strlen(to_send));` has problems.  Typical `int` (which is the type expected with `%d`) needs up to 11 + 1 `char`, not 10.  e.g. `-2147483648`.  `strlen()` returns type `size_t` which may not match `%d`.  Perhaps you want `%zu` then 10 might be OK.  Code that uses `snprintf()` to prevent overruns and does not check the return value of `snprintf()` is trading one problem for another. Better to check its return value.

Comment: `size_t len = strtoul(slen, NULL, 10);` would benefit with a prior `slen[sizeof slen -1] = 0;`.  Recommend this defensive coding as input from another process should be not fully trusted.